# Eclipse GCC linking to a static library fails?

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, linker, g++

I have a C++ project in Eclipse and I have a smaller project that I have wrappers around network Manager libraries to make life easier for myself when I call NM C functions from my C++ code.

So I created a simple file, nmi.c and nmi.h and I created libnmi.a:

```
gcc -c nmi.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0 libnm` -o nmi.o
ar rcs libnmi.a nmi.o
gcc -c -fPIC nmi.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0 libnm` -o nmi.o
```

The library works fine, or it seems. I have a test code a.cpp and I compile it with:

```
${CC}g++ a.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0 libnm` -L. -lnmi -o acpp
```

and acpp is created just fine and works.

But when I try to integrate it into Eclipse is where I run into major issues.

I try to replicate what I've done in a.cpp which is include nmi.h in extern "C":

```
extern "C" {
    #include "nmi.h"
}
```

and compile with -L and -l set through the BUILD settings in the interface. I also set the pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0 libnm as argument in g++ compiler call and g++ linker calls but I get the following errors:

```
 Invoking: Cross G++ Linker arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \`/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0\`
```

> ```
> nmi.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `nm_client_get_type'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `nm_client_add_connection_finish'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `nm_connection_get_type'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `nm_connection_get_path'
> /opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnmi.a(nmi.o): In function `add_connection':
> nmi.c:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `nm_simple_connection_new'
> nmi.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `nm_setting_connection_new'
> nmi.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `nm_utils_uuid_generate'
> nmi.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `nm_setting_get_type'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `nm_connection_add_setting'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `nm_setting_gsm_new'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `nm_setting_get_type'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `nm_connection_add_setting'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `nm_setting_ip4_config_new'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `nm_setting_get_type'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `nm_connection_add_setting'
> nmi.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to  `nm_client_add_connection_async'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [LocatorSource_Falcon] Error 1
> ```

But when I run everything in command for a test code:

```
${CC}g++ a.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib glib-2.0 libnm` -L. -lnmi -o acpp
```

/wtw/falcon/build/locatorsource/DriverCenter/LocatorSource/branches/ModemManager/Src/ThirdPartyLibs/NetworkManager $ ll
    total 68
    drwxrwxr-x 4 a a  4096 May 18 18:05 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 7 a a  4096 Apr 21 14:03 ../
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 a a 14287 May 18 18:05 acpp*

Am I missing something in Eclipse that it seems like it's digging deep down into the library and needing to find everything that the static library is linking to?

Thanks